# Check creation of new file/folder is allowed in client server using PHP code

Tags: php, file, directory

In my site, I want to create new files or folders dynamically. I need to check if I have the permission to create new files and folders. How can i do this?

I also want to check if it is allowed PHP code execution is allowed in the client’s server. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use: `is_writable`

eg:

```
if(is_writable('/path/to/your/dir/'))
{

}
```

from PHP Manual:

**is_writable**

Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is writable. The filename argument may be a directory name allowing you to check if a directory is writable.

Keep in mind that PHP may be accessing the file as the user id that the web server runs as (often 'nobody'). Safe mode limitations are not taken into account.

Comment: Combined with `is_dir` you can determine that the path is indeed a directory http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: This may be of some help (see canWriteTo method) http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6856-PHP-Manipulates-files-in-directories-recursively.html

Answer (score 1):

use the following code to check permission of a directory

```
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/directory')), -4);
```

and if you want to change the permission [refer this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)